# How to list files in curdir not ignored by npm's .gitignore and .npmignore

Tags: node.js, npm, gitignore

How to see the list of files in the current directory that will be published by `npm publish`, in other words those files that are not being ignored by ignore rules of `.gitignore` and `.npmignore`.

I expect a specific command line or Node.js module/function that could do the job.

Comment: I just tried 'unignored' npm module, it simply does not work.

Comment: probably use `npm pack` and see tar which files are there?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this really helps, but take a look at the `files` field of `package.json`
**https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files**

In the `files` field of your `package.json` you can specify which files will be published.

I think that what you include in the `files` field will override any `.gitignore` rule, but not `.npmignore` rules. I'm not sure though.